# Child process returns nil for fork call

Tags: ruby, unix, process

```
puts "Process #{Process.pid} started"
return_value = fork
puts "Process #{Process.pid} returned #{return_value}"
puts "Process #{Process.pid} exited"
```

Above ruby code printed this output to STDOUT

```
Process 6644 started
Process 6644 returned 6645
Process 6644 exited
Process 6645 returned 
Process 6645 exited
```

When parent process executes `fork`, it returns the pid of child process. When the child process calls `fork` why is it returning `nil`, shouldn't this be a recursive-kind-of-call? Like.. child also forks another child process.. and that child process forks another process..etc., Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you distinguish in the code whether the code is running in the parent process or in the child process: the parent process receives the PID of the forked child, and the child gets `nil`.

Personally, I prefer to use the syntax:

```
pid = fork do
  # this is the code that will be executed by the child
end

# this is the code executed by parent
```

Since most of the time, child is supposed to do something other than the parent process, this code reflects the intent much better.

Comment: If I do not use _block_ syntax in fork like the code from the question, may I say that the child process will only execute the code after "fork" and that is the reason child process didn't execute `puts "Process #{Process.pid} started"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do missing a point I you refer the Ruby fork documentation calling a fork with block executed the code below it twice one for the parent and other for the child (fork process) with child fork **return nil**

You If you inspect your output

```
Process 6644 started  -- Parent Process Started
Process 6644 returned 6645 -- Parent Process displaying the retrun value = child process id
Process 6644 exited   -- Parent Process exiting
Process 6645 returned  -- Child Process forked earlier and since there return value is nil
Process 6645 exited  -- Child Process exiting
```

Check Ruby [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-fork) on fork  this form of fork declaration is sightly confusing from the block thing which @psyho has answered .

I advice you to use the follow the same declaration that @psycho answered since it is that confusing

Hope this help